# Merging datasets in Bigquery

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

After upgrading to Google Analytics in my Firebase project I linked up to a new GA property and had to re-setup my Bigquery integration (after accidentally linking/unlinking my GA account, my integration was turned off). I got it fixed by linking again but now all new data is fed into a new `analytics_*` dataset.

Since all my queries are referring to the old dataset it would be quite the effort renaming all of them to link to both the new dataset + the old dataset. Is it possible to either:

- Change the destination table in the firebase Bigquery export (choosing the old dataset instead of the newly created one)
- Somehow merge the two datasets (instead of copying them)

I understood it's impossible to rename datasets which would solve my issue if I could change the name of the new set to the old name and copy the contents of the old set to the new one.

**UPDATE**

I was able to fix it by:

- unlinking the project again
- using the firebase management api to link my firebase project again to the original GA property
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/addGoogleAnalytics#request-body

This started feeding data back into my old property. I subsequently copied the partitioned tables from the newly created property/ table back into the old property (in Bigquery) using the same naming convention (eg. `events_20190101`) which correctly copied them in the partitioned dataset. I had to append some intraday events as well to the existing partitioned dataset but this solved my problem in the end.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [BigQuery export schema document](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846) for each single Firebase project linked to BigQuery, a single dataset named "analytics_" is added to your Bigquery project and such ID refers to your Analytics Property ID located in the Analytics Settings in Firebase (Settings -> Integrations -> Google Analytics).
It seems that this ID is generated automatically when you [set up a property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042508?hl=en&ref_topic=1009620) and it can be manually changed to a custom one.

Additionally, there's no way to merge datasets than copy the data between them. Thus, you could consider using [scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query) to append the data in your old dataset.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks a lot for the response! I managed to fix it eventually. I added my steps in the post. Unfortunately you cannot select a custom property (its in development). I indeed found merging does not work, very annoying. I considered scheduled queries but wasn't keen on paying extra for it :)

Comment: Good catch there!